# Why isn't caliburn.micro automatically creating my ViewModel in a Windows Phone 8 app?

Tags: windows-phone-8, caliburn.micro

Using caliburn.micro 1.5.2, I have

- `Views\MainPage.xaml`
- `ViewModels\MainPageViewModel.cs`

as well as

```
container.PerRequest<MainPageViewModel>();
```

in my `Bootstrapper.Configure` method.

According to the [Naming Conventions](http://caliburnmicro.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=View%2FViewModel%20Naming%20Conventions) this means my ViewModel should be auto-magically created and set to the DataContext of my views. But the ViewModel constructor is never hit even though the view is successfully created. Why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because Windows Phone 8 apps are Silverlight, and non-public classes are a no-no for frameworks to deal with.

Once you make the ViewModel class `public` (instead of the implicit default of internal), all is well.